Conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y-X=c$ and X and Y are Bivariate Gaussian (not independent) distributed with covariance matrix, $\Sigma$
Suppose we have two joint bivariate Gaussian random variables, $X$ and $Y$ distributed as $[X;Y] \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is the known covariance matrix. The pdf for bivariate normal can be found here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html.
How can we find the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y-X = c$ where $c$ is some known constant?
My attempt:
I started by defining $Z = Y - X$ and decided to find the conditional PDF:
$f_{X|Z}(X=x|Z=z) = \frac{f_{X, Z}(x,z)}{f_Z(z)}$.
(i) $f_Z(z)$ is easy to compute since $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 - 2\sigma_{XY})$.
(ii) To compute $f_{X, Z}(x,z)$, I tried to compute the CDF first with hopes to differentiate it after:
$F_{X, Z}(x_0, z_0) = \mathbb{P}(X < x_0, Z < z_0) = \mathbb{P}(X < x_0, Y - X < z_0) = \mathbb{P}(X < x_0, Y < z_0 - x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_0} \int_{-\infty}^{z_0 - x} f_{X, Y}(x, y) dydx$, but this integral is hard to compute, and I could not get Wolfram Alpha to compute it for me either.
Is there a simpler way to do this?

$(X,Z)$ is bivariate normal with mean zero and and $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Z) = \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) - \mathrm{Var}(X)$. That gives you the p.d.f. $f_{X,Z}$.
